# Google container-bound script project name

Tags: google-apps-script

The first time a google [container-bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scripts_containers) is saved, it asks for a project name:

> **Rename project**
>
> Enter new project name ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

What is this project name used for? Why is it not enough that the *container* (e.g. a spreadsheet) is saved with a name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best reason I see is to allow having multiple script projects in the same spreadsheet.

Now, one can wonder why it would be useful to have more than one project bounded to a single spreadsheet but that's another story:-) .